# Adobe Air Global Application Data

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Does anyone know of a "Global" Application data for Adobe Air?

`File.applicationStorageDirectory` stores within the users area?

But we need the application to store information for the whole computer.

Something such as Windows: C:\ProgramData or AllUsers but there doesn't seem to be an official way to use these areas. (Trying to keep this as Standard as possible)

But there doesn't seem to be a `File.allUsersApplicationStorage` or `File.globalApplicationData anything.`

Now I know I could do something such as below for Windows Vista/7

```
var _path:String = File.applicationDirectory.nativePath;
// _np: C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgName\
_path = _path.substr(0, _np.indexOf(File.separator) + 1);
// _np: C:\
var _file = new File(_path).resolvePath("ProgramData/ProgName");
```

but I do not know what to do for WinXP, MacOS or Linux.

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: What's wrong with File.applicationStorageDirectory again please?

Comment: Each OSUser would be treated as a new install since there would be no ApplicationData stored. We need them all to act as one. No matter if Administrator logs onto the computer or JoeBloggs or MrKipling.

Comment: Well if that's sort of kiosk application (for a private use) — you could take responsibility and install it into *pseudocode* File.applicationDirectory.parentDirectory.resolvePath("ApplicationNameData").
If that's a common public app — no easy options... Technically you can try same, but that's not very kinda ethical...

Comment: Can't use ApplicationDirectory. I can read from it, but cannot write to ApplicationDirectory due to UserRights

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you just use `File.applicationDirectory`? (Or rather, a subdirectory of it.) That would store your information in the application directory, and would be accessible from all users.

It might not be ideal, but it works.

Comment: File.applicationDirectory is nor writable (anymore)

Comment: As Pavel Said. I have UAC turned onto full on my machine, just to make sure of this too.